# Can I use a SSD Master, & mirror it with a HDD?

Tags: hard-drive, backup, ssd

As the name suggests,I haven't used Ubuntu past the stage of just trying it out so far. I have grown to see though that it is a great OS & am currently typing this on a laptop that belongs to my auntie who is a light PC user that only has this one PC that she uses just for browsing/email, word-processing/spreadsheets, & for storing her pictures from her travels, but it's for the latter I seek your advice. The spec of the laptop is in the link below.

http://www.toshiba.co.uk/discontinued-products/satellite-pro-p300-19q/

I have replaced the old HDD with a Corsair 120GB SSD (can't remember type now but has trim (if that still matters)) as the main drive, but I'd like to install a 160GB as a mirror, that if not is a complete mirror, at least gives a true (as live as possible) backup of the main folders, so she doesn't have to worry about pretty much anything, short of loosing the laptop itself.

So people I ask, am I asking too much of this old but otherwise solid laptop & Ubuntu, or is they a easy(or ish) way of doing what I'm thinking here?

Kind regards,

Karl

Comment: Have you checked out RAID?

Comment: I've gone through the bios & couldn't do anything through that.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do it through Ubuntu itself, & honestly, from a hardware POV can Ubuntu raid a 120 SSD with a 160 HDD? I apologise, but I really am a noob here :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a (approx.) 120Gb partition on each of the drive and use the Linux software RAID mirror to create a volume.

Assuming this is a clean install...

1. Select the manual partitioning method and create a partition for /boot on each drive (same size).
2. Next create partition(s) for the rest of your filesystem on each drive (the partitions must be the same size -- if they are different, the smaller size will be used and the remaining space lost).
3. Tell the partitioner to use each of the 4 partitions as RAID space.
4. Continue to the software RAID configuration.
5. Create a new RAID mirror device and select the same size partitions on each drive.
6. Repeat for other partitions.
7. When you finish with the software RAID configuration, you should see the new RAID devices and can continue formatting them instead of your regular partitions.